# Can a Bitcoin block be less than 1mb?

Tags: blockchain, block, blocksize

Can a Bitcoin block be less than 1mb?

To my understanding, a miner receives broadcasts. However, if not enough transactions come in, then would it just prematurely hash the block?

Comment: What do you mean by "prematurely"? Most miners hash every second they possibly can, otherwise their mining power is wasted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Let's calculate the minimum size of a block:

- The [block header](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#block-headers) must be exactly 80 bytes.  This is the only part of the block that miners actually mine; the rest of the block is data that the header securely references.
- The transaction count.  This isn't part of the block header and it isn't part of the block data, but it's part of the peer-to-peer protocol [block message](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#block) so it gets counted towards the block size.  For blocks with 253 or fewer transactions, this is 1 byte.
- The coinbase transaction, the only required transaction in a block.  The coinbase transaction has the following fields with these minimum values:

  - 4 bytes -- version field
  - 1 byte  -- number of inputs (always 1 for coinbase transactions)
  - 32 bytes -- [outpoint](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#outpoint) txid; always 32 0x00 bytes for coinbase transactions
  - 4 bytes -- outpoint index; always 4 0xff bytes for coinbase transactions
  - 1 byte -- number of bytes in coinbase field (input script); always 1 byte for coinbase transactions because there's a 100-byte limit
  - 4 bytes -- block height as a data push; required by [BIP34](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki)
  - 4 bytes -- [sequence number](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#locktime-and-sequence-number)
  - 1 byte -- number of outputs, we're not going to have any (making the block reward and transaction fees paid in this block permanently unspendable; no real miner would do this)
  - 4 bytes -- [locktime](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#locktime-and-sequence-number)
  - **Total:** 55 bytes

**Total minimum block size:** 80 + 1 + 55 = 136 bytes

Practically, the smallest reasonable blocks are in the 180-byte range.

Comment: Empty `vout` would make the transaction [invalid](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L725-L726). You would need to have one output of 0 BTC, 0 length, null script for a total 9 bytes (8 byte value, one byte VarInt). This would also be an anyone can spend output as a null script can be satisfied by pushing anything to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

[This](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000000fc5e782386b679ad5833ea2cddf4e06ebb403d725655a69) is one such block. It's 312 kB.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks have to have at least one transaction: They must contain a coinbase which is the transaction that spends the block reward.

For example this [block with only one transaction](https://blockchain.info/block-index/512049/00000000000000000429a0c4fbe735b2d8b493daedf0207728543f748c262437)  is only    `0.246 kB`.